# API PLATFORM CUSTUM OPERATION Provide Value for Data Argument

Tags: php, symfony

Good Afternoon. 
I'm using Symfony 4.1.1 and APIPlatorm to create an API.
I'm trying to create a custum Post Operation to Create a user in DataBase with a crypted Password.

I've follow the procedure describe in https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations
But i've to following Error:

> Controller \"App\Controller\UtilisateurSpecial\" requires that you
>   provide a value for the \"$data\" argument. Either the argument is
>   nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has
>   been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this
>   one.

That is my configuration. Can You please Help me to solve this problem?

src\Entity\Utilisateur.php

```
 <?php

   namespace App\Entity;

   use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
   use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

   /**
    * @ApiResource(
    *     collectionOperations={
    *     "post",
    *     "special"={
    *         "method"="POST",
    *         "path"="/utilisateurs/special.{_format}",
    *          "requirements"={
    *              "_format": "\s+"
    *           },
    *         "controller"=App\Controller\UtilisateurSpecial::class,
    *         "defaults"={"_api_receive"=false}
    *     }
    * })
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UtilisateurRepository")
    * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Cet email est déjà enregistré en base.")
    * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Cet identifiant est déjà enregistré en base")
    * 
    */
   class Utilisateur implements UserInterface, \Serializable
   {
       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
       private $id;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
        * @Assert\NotBlank()
        * @Assert\Length(max=25)
        */
       private $username;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string")
        */
       private $password;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
        * @Assert\NotBlank()
        * @Assert\Length(max=60)
        * @Assert\Email()
        */
       private $email;

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
        */
       private $isActive;

        /**
        * @var array
        * @ORM\Column(type="array")
        */
       private $roles;

       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->isActive = true;
           $this->roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
       }

       /*
        * Get id
        */
       public function getId()
       {
           return $this->id;
       }

       public function getUsername()
       {
           return $this->username;
       }

       public function setUsername($username)
       {
           $this->username = $username;
           return $this;
       }


       public function getPassword()
       {
           return $this->password;
       }

       public function setPassword($password)
       {
           $this->password = $password;
           return $this;
       }

       /*
        * Get email
        */
       public function getEmail()
       {
           return $this->email;
       }

       /*
        * Set email
        */
       public function setEmail($email)
       {
           $this->email = $email;
           return $this;
       }

       /*
        * Get isActive
        */
       public function getIsActive()
       {
           return $this->isActive;
       }

       /*
        * Set isActive
        */
       public function setIsActive($isActive)
       {
           $this->isActive = $isActive;
           return $this;
       }

        // modifier la méthode getRoles
        public function getRoles()
        {
            return $this->roles; 
        }

        public function setRoles(array $roles)
        {
            if (!in_array('ROLE_USER', $roles))
            {
                $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
            }
            foreach ($roles as $role)
            {
                if(substr($role, 0, 5) !== 'ROLE_') {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Chaque rôle doit commencer par 'ROLE_'");
                }
            }
            $this->roles = $roles;
            return $this;
        }

       public function getSalt()
       {
           // pas besoin de salt puisque nous allons utiliser bcrypt
           // attention si vous utilisez une méthode d'encodage différente !
           // il faudra décommenter les lignes concernant le salt, créer la propriété correspondante, et renvoyer sa valeur dans cette méthode
           return null;
       }

       public function eraseCredentials()
       {
       }

       /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
       public function serialize()
       {
           return serialize(array(
               $this->id,
               $this->username,
               $this->password,
               $this->isActive,
               // voir remarques sur salt plus haut
               // $this->salt,
           ));
       }

       /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
       public function unserialize($serialized)
       {
           list (
               $this->id,
               $this->username,
               $this->password,
               $this->isActive,
               // voir remarques sur salt plus haut
               // $this->salt
           ) = unserialize($serialized);
       }


   }
```

src/controller/UtilisateurSpecial

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Utilisateur;
use App\Service\UtilisateurService;

class UtilisateurSpecial
{
   private $utilisateurService;

   public function __construct(UtilisateurService $utilisateurService)
   {
       $this->utilisateurService = $utilisateurService;
   }

   public function __invoke( $data): Utilisateur
   {
       $this->utilisateurService->addUtilisateur($data->getUsername, $data->getPassword);

       return $data;
   }
}
```

Can you please help me to solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "API PLATFORM CUSTUM OPERATION"? Please reread [ask], then rephrase that a bit. Chances are you intendet those as keywords, for which you should use tags. Make sure you read the tags' descriptions though before applying them!

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at your config:

```
  /**
    * @ApiResource(
    *     collectionOperations={
    *     "post",
    *     "special"={
    *         "method"="POST",
    *         "path"="/utilisateurs/special.{_format}",
    *          "requirements"={
    *              "_format": "\s+"
    *           },
    *         "controller"=App\Controller\UtilisateurSpecial::class,
    *         "defaults"={"_api_receive"=false}
    *     }
    * })
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UtilisateurRepository")
    * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Cet email est déjà enregistré en base.")
    * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Cet identifiant est déjà enregistré en base")
    * 
    */
```

By default, API Platform would pass the resource to your custom operation, in your case the object of class Utilisateur. Since it's a POST operation, it'll be an Utilisateur instance created based on your input in the request body.

See what API Platform documentation says on this:

> If you want to bypass the automatic retrieval of the entity, you can
>   set the parameter `_api_receive` to `false`.  This way, it will skip
>   the `Read`, `Deserialize` and `Validate` listeners (see the event
>   system for more information).

If you set _api_receive = true there's nothing API Platform can pass to your custom operation. You've disabled automatic deserialization. So, you should not have a $data argument on __invoke() at all in this case.

Instead, you should define your __invoke() as:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request) { 
}
```

This way you get access to the current Request object for anything you might need it.

Answer (score 0):

If $data is an user object... You should do three things.

First, import the class controller (use) on the entity.

Second, remove

```
"defaults"={"_api_receive"=false}
```

from the api resource annotation in the user entity.

Third, $data should be:

```
public function __invoke(User $data): Utilisateur { 
}
```